# Info button does not work when located in the header of sortable column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have this situation: I need to have an info button in the sortable column's header, so I put things like this in JavaScript file where I have table description:

```
{
  key: "kkk",
  label: Y.PI.I.getString("label", "label_shown") + '<div class="help-button help-button-inline"> ' + Y.PI.I.getString("hint_text", "text in info button") + '</div>',
  sortable: true
}
```

but in this case the info button does not show info message when clicking on its icon. It seems that info button and sortable are incompatible.

Comment: Where is the callback code for when the button is clicked? Is the button part of the sortable handle?